# How do I pass functions from a parent component to handle events in a child component using Next.JS?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, next.js, react-hooks

I'm trying to develop a Next.js component (FormGenerator.jsx) to automatically create a form based on information (an array of objects) passed to that component. Within the FormGenerator, it iterates through each object in the array, rendering a child component (TextField, TextArea, etc.) based on that data in the object. My goal for this is to streamline and maintain consistency throughout 40+ forms on my website.

I'm able to render all necessary components and pass the necessary information to said child components; however, my issue revolves around event handlers. In my parent component (FormGenerator), I'm storing the states of all child components, including the values and an isInvalid boolean for said child components. In order for me to do this, I'm passing an onBlur and handleChange functions to the child components. The onBlur function will be used for validation whereas the handleChange function will be used to update the state.

Unfortunately, it appears that the onBlur and handleChange functions are not being triggered when values are entered or when the user clicks off an element. I'll provide my code down below. I removed all unnecessary Tailwind.css stylings for simplicity. Additionally, I only included the TextField component since this is my trial run; additional form elements will be added during development.

src/app/page.jsx:

```
const components [{...}...] // List of components to generate using FormGenerator

const page = () => {
  return (
    ...
    <FormGenerator 
       components={components}
    />
    ...
  )
}

export default page
```

src/app/components/FormGenerator.jsx:

```
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "./FormGeneratorLib/TextField";

const FormGenerator = ({ title, desc, components }) => {
  const initValues = ...
  const initErrors = ...

  const initState = { values: initValues, isInvalid: initErrors };
  const [state, setState] = useState(initState);
  const { values, isInvalid } = state;

  ...
 
  const onBlur = (e) => {
    console.error("onBlur Triggered") // Just for testing purposes
  }

  // function onBlur(event) { // First attempt at this
  //   console.error("onBlur Triggered");
  //   const input = event.target;
  //
  //   // Validation
  //
  //   setState((prev) => ({
  //     ...prev,
  //     isInvalid: {
  //       ...prev.isInvalid,
  //       [input.name]: true,
  //     },
  //   }));
  // }

  // Handles Component Change Event and Updates Value
  const handleChange = ({ target }) =>
    setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      values: {
        ...prev.values,
        [target.name]: target.value,
      },
    }));

  return (
     ...
        <form>
          {components.map((component, index) => {
            switch (component.component) {
              case "TextField":
                return (
                  <TextField
                    key={index}
                    fieldName={component.fieldName}
                    label={component.label}
                    errorMessage={component.errorMessage}
                    fieldType={component.fieldType}
                    placeholderText={component.placeholderText}
                    isRequired={component.isRequired}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    value={values[component.fieldName]}
                    isInvalid={isInvalid[component.fieldName]}
                  />
                );
              default:
                return null;
            }
          })}

          <button
            className="disabled:opacity-30"
            onClick={onSubmit}
            disabled={!values[0]} // To be updated
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
     ...
  );
};

export default FormGenerator;
```

src/app/components/FormGeneratorLib/TextField.jsx:

```
"use client"

import React, { useState } from 'react'

const TextField = ({ fieldName, label, errorMessage, fieldType, placeholderText, isRequired, value, onChange, onBlur, isInvalid }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <input 
        name={fieldName}
        type={fieldType}
        required={isRequired}
        placeholder={placeholderText}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        className={
          isInvalid
           ? 'border border-red-500'
           : '...'
        }
      />
      <p className={
        isInvalid
          ? '...'
          : 'hidden'
      }
      >{errorMessage}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TextField
```

Over the past two days, I have been tirelessly researching, watching many YouTube videos, and asking peers for assistance, but to no avail. I've tried debugging my code as well, but I've ran into issues with that too so its been a lot of back and forth.

Ultimately, I would like to have the parent state updated when a user enters values and for the onChange and onBlur event handlers to work.

If you have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue, that would be greatly appreciated! As well, if you think there is a better way to go about this idea, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried getting the event(e) intead of deconstructing the target on handleChange and see if you get any data?  const handleChange = ( e ) => ...

Comment: @Shibi I have, yes. I've tried console logging the event and values, but it appears the event never triggers since no log is outputted?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of passing the props use the `createContext` and pass all the values to the child component or onblur and handleChange like the example given below

Eg:

```
   
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
import TextField from "./FormGeneratorLib/TextField";

  export const inputContext = createContext()

const FormGenerator = ({ title, desc, components }) => {
  .......
  const onBlur = (e) => {
    console.error("onBlur Triggered") // Just for testing purposes
  }

  // Handles Component Change Event and Updates Value
  const handleChange = ({ target }) =>
    setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      values: {
        ...prev.values,
        [target.name]: target.value,
      },
    }));

  return (
     ...
        <form>
          {components.map((component, index) => {
            switch (component.component) {
              case "TextField":
                return (
                  <inputContext.Provider value={{ onBlur, handleChange }}>
                  <TextField
                    key={index}
                    fieldName={component.fieldName}
                    label={component.label}
                    errorMessage={component.errorMessage}
                    fieldType={component.fieldType}
                    placeholderText={component.placeholderText}
                    isRequired={component.isRequired}
                    value={values[component.fieldName]}
                    isInvalid={isInvalid[component.fieldName]}
                  />
                  </inputContext.Provider>
                );
              default:
                return null;
            }
          })}
     ...
  );
};
export default FormGenerator;
```

And In your textfield component

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import {inputContext } from './FormGenerator.jsx'

const TextField = ({ fieldName, label, errorMessage, fieldType, placeholderText, isRequired, value, isInvalid }) => {
const {contextInput} = useContext(inputContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <input 
        name={fieldName}
        type={fieldType}
        required={isRequired}
        placeholder={placeholderText}
        value={value}
        onChange={contextInput.handleChange}
        onBlur={contextInput.onBlur}
        className={
          isInvalid
           ? 'border border-red-500'
           : '...'
        }
      />
```